# Protect data protection key files with a certificate on ASP .NET Core 2 and Linux

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, .net-core, data-protection

I'm trying to protect keys at rest using `ProtectKeysWithCertificate` method, but I'm running into some issues when code runs on Linux (RHEL7). If I use `ProtectKeysWithCertificate("thumbprint")` method, it can't find the certificate under /etc/ssl/certs location. So I tried searching Local Machine\Root on Linux and loading X509 cert on my own from the cert store with `ProtectKeysWithCertificate()` method. That loads the cert for encryption, but it's unable to decrypt anything (I get 'Unable to retrieve the decryption key' error) and just creates new key files every time the service restarts.

The only way I could protect data keys at rest on Linux is to use PFX file and supply my own password, but that means I have to store password in plaintext somewhere, which I really don't want to do.

Any help on this or how to get it work on Linux would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I'll post my answer in case someone is looking for something similar on Linux. To load X509 certificate with private key, I had to use Bouncy Castle .NET Core library to read the private key and get RSACryptoServiceProvider object. Once I had public cert and private key file, I used .NET Core CopyWithPrivateKey(csp) method to get a copy of X509 cert with private key, which was then compatible with ProtectKeysWithCertificate() method.